# Query 2 different items within the same field and the same table

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm very new to SQL and I don't know how to query 2 different items within the same field and the same table.
I'm writing this in Excel VBA using SQL via oledb to attach to a PostGreSQL datasource

Basically I have 2 queries that I need to combine into one query.
The first query is the primary group.
I need to first find all those people with the code C10%. Then of those with C10 who also have the code R110%

The codes are in the srch table and the people names are in the person table, these are joined by master_id=p.entity_id

Here are the 2 queries I need to combine:

```
Dim DIAG As String
    DIAG = "SELECT DISTINCT master_id, eventdate, code, term, surname, forename " _
    & "FROM srch INNER JOIN person p ON master_id=p.entity_id " _
    & "WHERE code LIKE 'C10..%' " _
    & "ORDER BY master_id "


Dim DIAG As String
    DIAG = "SELECT DISTINCT master_id, eventdate, code, term, surname, forename " _
    & "FROM srch INNER JOIN person p ON master_id=p.entity_id " _
    & "WHERE code LIKE 'R110%' " _
    & "ORDER BY master_id "
```

The tables have 100 of rows and each has a master_id that identifies the person. Therefore row would be master_id = 1 and code = C10.
The next could be master_id= 1 and code R110.

You are correct in that different codes cannot exist on the same row

Does this help.

```
person table
entity_id | surname | forename
1         | Smith   | John
2         | Mouse   | Mickey
3

srch table
master_id | code | term | eventdate
1         |C10   |  DM  | 01/01/2000
2         |R110  |  AL  | 01/01/2001
1         |R110  |  AL  | 01/01/2002
```

I need to find person 1

```
Result
master_id|code|term| eventdate |surname|forename
   1     |R110| AL | 01/01/2002| Smith | John
```

Comment: use OR and like where code like x or y

Comment: I tried using WHERE code LIKE 'C10%' AND code LIKE 'R110%' but it returns nothing. OR does work but that is not what I need as I only want to return those with both.

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using mysql <> sql server <> postgresql.

Comment: The data is held in PostGreSQL. I am using oledb to connect to PG and writing it in Excel VBA.

Comment: @BradleyS Can you please clarify? Does a code need to contain R110 AND C10 (eg. `R110_C10..`) or are you looking for codes that are either `R110` or `C10..`

Comment: I have edited my question to explain the table structure better.

Comment: The same master_id needs to find BOTH codes C10 AND R110 on different rows. So I know which Master_ids (persons) have both codes

Comment: @BradleyS.  What about the term and event_date columns? If there's a row with a  C10 code, when we look for a matching row with an R110 code... do the term and event_date have to match the values from the row with the C10 code, or are we just looking for any row with R10 for the same master_id ? (If the term and event_date do have to match, do we consider a NULL value to match a NULL value?) How we write the query depends on the answer to those questions.

Comment: @BradleyS... and when we do find person 1, do we want to return two rows ...one with the C10 code and the other with the R110 code ? (This is where a sample result would be beneficial.)

Comment: No the term and eventdate will just return the data associated line with the found match of code R110

Comment: The result only needs to show the data from the R110 row. The C10 code is only for a match and isn't needed.

Comment: Sample result added to initial question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the column references aren't qualified, we can't tell which table each column reference refers to.

---

SUGGESTION: as an aid to future readers of the SQL, please consider qualifying *all* column references with the table name, or even better, a short (unique) table alias. Then the future reader won't be scouring the table definitions to figure out which table contains which column.) Also consider what is going to happen with this SQL statement when a column of the same name is added to another table used in the query.)

---

We'll just have to guess at which table contains which columns.

I'd suggest a pattern using a GROUP BY clause, rather than DISTINCT.

And I suggest computing an aggregate on the result of an expression that tests  whether an included row satisfies the particular condition.

And then performing a test on the aggregate, to see if any rows existed (within the group) where the condition evaluated to TRUE.

As an example: (not tested)

```
SELECT s.master_id
     , s.eventdate
     , s.code
     , s.term
     , p.surname
     , p.forename
  FROM srch s
 INNER
  JOIN person p 
    ON p.entity_id = s.master_id
 WHERE ( s.code LIKE 'C10..%' OR s.code LIKE 'R110%' )
 GROUP
    BY s.master_id
     , s.eventdate
     , s.code
     , s.term
     , p.surname
     , p.forename
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.code LIKE 'C10..%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN s.code LIKE 'R110%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
 ORDER BY s.master_id
```

The **CASE** expressions will evaluate to either 1 or 0, for each row. The SUM() aggregate will total the 1s and 0s up. The return from the aggregate will be greater than zero if there was any row (within a "group") that satisfied the condition.

If there are no rows (within the group) with  code LIKE 'R110%', the SUM() will evaluate to zero, and the comparison will evaluate to FALSE, and the row will not be returned.

NOTE: The comparison of the aggregates is in a HAVING clause because the results from the aggregates is not available when the conditions in the WHERE clause are evaluated, when the rows are accessed.

**FOLLOWUP**

Doh! That query above isn't going to return rows. That's my bad. There's a reason we test against some test cases. It helps us identify doofus problems like the one in the query I suggested above.

It's impossible for that query to return any rows. The code column (as I hadn't really noticed) is in the GROUP BY clause. So at least one of the aggregate functions in the HAVING clause is guaranteed to evaluate to zero.

(My problem was that I hadn't noticed that code was a column in the GROUP BY. Doh!)

---

If all of the columns in the SELECT list need to match, *except* for the "code" column... (I hate to use an expensive correlated subquery when we don't have to...)  we could add "EXISTS (correlated subquery).

If master_id is a foreign key reference to entity_id in person, and entity_id is the primary key of person...  we could put off the join operation until *after* we had the results from srch.

Does term and event also need to match, or just the code? How we write the query depends on that...

---

Based on the responses in the comments, term and event_date don't need to match. We're looking for rows in srch for the same person (master_id) that have at least one row with the C10 code and at least one row with the R110 code.

Identifying those values of master_id follows the same pattern in the query above, using the GROUP BY and conditional tests on aggregates in the HAVING clause.

This is a query that should return the master_id values that have *both* a C10 code and an R110 code. This is something we can test... it doesn't return the whole resultset, in only gets us the master_id values we want to return:

```
SELECT r.master_id
  FROM srch r
 WHERE ( r.code LIKE 'C10..%' OR r.code LIKE 'R110%' )
 GROUP
    BY r.master_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'C10..%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'R110%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Once we get that, we can use that query as an inline view... wrap in parens, assign an alias and reference it like it was a table. For example:

```
SELECT q.*
  FROM ( SELECT r.master_id
           FROM srch r
          WHERE ( r.code LIKE 'C10..%' OR r.code LIKE 'R110%' )
          GROUP
             BY r.master_id
         HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'C10..%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            AND SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'R110%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
       ) q
```

We should test whether PostgreSQL will run that. If we can't get that to run, there's no point in building on it. Once we confirm that runs, we can add a join to the srch table, get the rows that have a matching master_id with a C10 or R110 code.

```
SELECT q.master_id
     , s.code
     , s.term
     , s.event_date
  FROM ( SELECT r.master_id
           FROM srch r
          WHERE ( r.code LIKE 'C10..%' OR r.code LIKE 'R110%' )
          GROUP
             BY r.master_id
         HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'C10..%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            AND SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'R110%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
       ) q
  JOIN srch s
    ON s.master_id = q.master_id
   AND s.code LIKE 'R110%'
```

We can add a join to the person table, to retrieve the given name and surname by primary key lookup.

```
  JOIN person p
    ON p.entity_id = s.master_id
```

add the appropriate column references to the SELECT list. The original queries had DISTINCT keyword. We can add that, or we could add GROUP BY clause. Whichever.

We can reference master_id from either the inline view or the srch table, or even the entity_id from the person table. The join conditions guarantee us they will all be non-null and equal to each other.

And wind up with something like this (desk checked only, not tested):

```
SELECT s.master_id
     , s.code
     , s.term
     , s.event_date
     , p.surname
     , p.forename
  FROM ( SELECT r.master_id
           FROM srch r
          WHERE ( r.code LIKE 'C10..%' OR r.code LIKE 'R110%' )
          GROUP
             BY r.master_id
         HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'C10..%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            AND SUM(CASE WHEN r.code LIKE 'R110%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
       ) q
  JOIN srch s
    ON s.master_id = q.master_id
   AND s.code LIKE 'R110%'
  JOIN person p
    ON p.entity_id = s.master_id
 GROUP
    BY s.master_id
     , s.code
     , s.term
     , s.event_date
     , p.surname
     , p.forename
 ORDER
    BY s.master_id
     , s.code
```

And, if I haven't made some other doofus mistake again, I expect this will return the result specified by OP.  (I've attempted to provide a few comments along the way, about how we went about building the query.)

I'd be interested in finding out how big of smoke ball this one makes.

**ANOTHER FOLLOWUP**

As an alternative, since we don't need to return the C10 rows, the query could actually be a little simpler. The inline view could just return us master_id values related to the C10 codes, and we can dispense with the HAVING clause with tests on the aggregates. This should return a result equivalent to the one above, perhaps even a little faster:

```
SELECT s.master_id
     , s.code
     , s.term
     , s.event_date
     , p.surname
     , p.forename
  FROM ( SELECT r.master_id
           FROM srch r
          WHERE r.code LIKE 'C10..%'
          GROUP
             BY r.master_id
       ) q
  JOIN srch s
    ON s.master_id = q.master_id
   AND s.code LIKE 'R110%'
  JOIN person p
    ON p.entity_id = s.master_id
 GROUP
    BY s.master_id
     , s.code
     , s.term
     , s.event_date
     , p.surname
     , p.forename
 ORDER
    BY s.master_id
     , s.code
```

Comment: Doh! My bad! I would have discovered that if I had tested it. And it's obvious why it won't return any rows... the "code" column is included in the GROUP BY.  If we removed "code" from the GROUP BY and the SELECT list, we might get some rows back. I thinking we could re-write this, with an EXISTS (corellated subquery) predicate. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I've included a table representation as well in my original question

Comment: @BradleyS:  If you're just looking for a query, scroll down to the *bottom* of my answer, to the last query. Above that is my pattern for building the query.... first identifying the master_id that we want to return... only those that have a C10 and R110 code.

Comment: @BradleyS:  I just read the comments you left.  If you only want to return the rows with the R110  codes, the required change to the query above is pretty easy. Just remove this part.  "**`s.code LIKE 'C10..%' OR`**"  (only the condition on "s.code"... leave the conditions on r.code, we need those.) And feel free to reformat the SQL text any way you want. And remove the outermost GROUP BY clause and use DISTINCT keyword in the SELECT list if you want. I find that by following the pattern like I do, it is *much* easier to write, test, rewrite and debug SQL statements.

Comment: @BradleyS: simplified the query. Since we are only returning the R110 rows, the inline view query can be simpler. Just return master_id associated with C10 rows. We'll pickup the matching R110 rows in the outer query. The GROUP BY/DISTINCT on the outermost query isn't necessary, unless there's a need to collapse duplicate rows.

Comment: That's it! Perfect. Thank you ever so much for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this wildcard and AND approach, to return both:

I'm assuming that `R110` might be followed by `C10..` or vice versa.

```
Dim DIAG As String
    DIAG = "SELECT DISTINCT master_id, eventdate, code, term, surname, forename " _
    & "FROM srch INNER JOIN person p ON master_id=p.entity_id " _
    & "WHERE code LIKE '*R110*' AND code LIKE '*C10..*' " _
    & "ORDER BY master_id "
```

Comment: This will never return ANY rows because there is no value that can meet both predicates at the same time. That would have to be OR. And the OP stated they tried this but they want only those that have both.

Comment: The two initial queries work fine separately, so finding the codes isn't the problem. I need to only return results if both codes exist. I know there are records with both when I search them separately.

Comment: So if the field value has both values, then the field value must be something like `foo_R110_foo_C10.._foo..` or `foo_C10.._foo_R110_foo..`, so a query term would need to match `'*R10*C10..*'` OR `'*C10..*R110*'`

Comment: Updated the SQL to match only when code contains R110 AND C10

Comment: Even with your edits this code will fail because you can't have a row that is both R110 AND C110

Comment: But the OP is suggesting that the code might contain both `OR does work but that is not what I need as I only want to return those with both. `

Comment: The matching patterns for code are *significantly* different than the OP original queries. What is the purpose the asterisk character? As far as I know, PostgreSQL hasn't extended the SQL standard LIKE comparison to support any wildcard characters other than percent and underscore. So those are just literal asterisk characters, and I can guarantee that there *no* rows that have a value in the code column that satisfies  both conditions.

Comment: OK this may them be my bad wording of names. In one table are 100 rows on row 1 is C10 and row 2 is R110 and so on. Each row has a unique master_id which identifies the person. So row one could be master_id=1 with C10 and row 2 could also have master_id = 1 with R110.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain the table structure better.

Comment: @Bradley: A clearer explanation is probably beneficial. But even without that, it's abundantly clear that the conditions on the code column (in the WHERE clauses of the original queries) are mutually exclusive. I applaud the efforts of those that attempt to provide an answer. But some of the answers (many notably of the "try this" variety) are barely more than guesses.

Comment: Thanks for the update to the question. My approach is dealing with code substrings in a single row (and using non PostGreSql wildcards. I'm AFK now, but what you need is a self join, or a subquery that uses EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark. This may or may not work because we still don't know which DBMS you are using. This should work for sql server and maybe for postgresql. You may have to tweak the syntax slightly depending on which DBMS you are actually using. No matter which system you are using please don't be scared to use aliases and formatting.

```
SELECT s.master_id
    , s.eventdate
    , count(distinct s.code) as CodeCount
    , s.term
    , p.surname
    , p.forename 
FROM srch s
INNER JOIN person p ON s.master_id = p.entity_id 
WHERE s.code LIKE 'C10..%' 
    OR s.code like 'R110%'
group by s.master_id
    , s.eventdate
    , s.term
    , p.surname
    , p.forename 
having count(distinct s.code) = 2
ORDER BY s.master_id
```

Comment: Questioner clearly states ` SQL via oledb to attach to a PostGreSQL datasource`

Comment: And the tag bombed everything. :)

Comment: What if code values for a given search are 'C10..abc' and 'C10..def', but no code values like 'R110%' at all? What if there is a code value like 'R110%'.  Seems like we can demonstrate cases where this would return rows it shouldn't, and wouldn't return rows it should.

Comment: @spencer7593 that is a valid point. I think it could easily produce some false positives. Not sure it would skip rows it shouldn't though.

Comment: Finding the codes isn't a problem when searched on there own in the 2 separate queries.

Comment: I used the above code by Sean Lange, but it returns an error " expected expression in COUNT"

Comment: @BradleyS the error is likely due to my code being geared for sql server. It is very likely that postgresql is a little different.

Comment: I have edited my question to explain the table structure better.